# Equating coefficients in a non-power-series equation

Tags: equation-solving

How can I use *Mathematica* to equate coefficients in a non-power-series equation?

For example, I would like to take an equation like the following:
$$af_x+\frac{b}{2}f_xf_y+chf_x=f_x+e^af_x+3f_xf_y+2bhf_x$$
and produce the following system:
$$a=1+e^a$$
$$\frac{b}{2}=3$$
$$c=2b$$
**EDIT:** This is a rather small example. If possible, I would prefer a solution that requires minimal human inspection of the original equation. The equations I will be working with will have many, perhaps hundreds of partial derivative terms, and it would be unfeasible to do things like individually pick them out. Ideally, I would like to specify only the unknowns I am interested in (in this case, {a, b, c}) and let *Mathematica* take it from there.

Comment: You can subtract rhs from lhs, use 'Variables', remove all that are not 'FreeQ' of '{a,b,c}', and then 'SolveAlways[lhs-rhs, remaining variables]'.

Comment: `SolveAlways[ a fx + b fx fy/2 + c h fx - (fx + Exp[a] fx + 3 fx fy + 2 b h fx) ==  0, {fx, fy, h}]` gives me `SolveAlways::tdep: The equations appear to involve the variables to be solved for in an essentially non-algebraic way.`

Comment: Ah. I was hoping it would handle that a=1+e^a. Another possibility is to find the fx etc. vars progrmatically, mult iply all by a new variable, say t. Now take a Series in t. The coeffs should be the things you want to equate to zero. (Traveling sans Mathematica so cannot test this in detail).

Comment: Actually, your first method works if I use another similar equation, like `SolveAlways[b fx fy + c h fx == 3 c fx fy + (a + b + 2 c) h fx, {fx, fy, h}]`. I assume the issue arises from the equation $a=1+e^a$, which *Mathematica* doesn't seem to like for being non-algebraic.

Comment: Is there a way to tell *Mathematica* not to try to solve the equations produced by `SolveAlways`, but to simply return them?

Comment: Maybe `Resolve` will be more reliable. `Resolve[ForAll[{fx, fy, h}, 
  a fx + b fx fy/2 + c h fx - (fx + Exp[a] fx + 3 fx fy + 2 b h fx) ==
    0]]` gives a viable result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also there is `MonomialList`.

```
coefficientRelations[expr_, params_] := Module[
  {vars},
  vars = DeleteCases[Variables[expr], 
    vv_ /; Internal`DependsOnQ[vv, params]];
  MonomialList[expr, vars] /. Thread[vars -> 1]
  ]
```

Your example is then as follows.

```
expr = a fx + b fx fy/2 + 
   c h fx - (fx + Exp[a] fx + 3 fx fy + 2 b h fx);
parameters = {a, b, c};

coefficientRelations[expr, parameters]

(* ut[104]= {-3 + b/2, -2 b + c, -1 + a - E^a} *)
```

Comment: Daniel, would you describe the function of ``Internal`DependsOnQ`` please?

Comment: Interestingly, I cannot find anything about `DependsOnQ` in the Documentation Center. At first, I thought it might be something like a complement of `FreeQ`, but there are cases in which they disagree. For example, `FreeQ[g[x], g]` is `False` whereas ``Internal`DependsOnQ[g[x], g]`` is `True`.

Comment: @DavidZhang just explained it. That is to say, it is a more nuanced version of `FreeQ`, that decides there is no dependency between e.g. `x` and `x[1]`. Also the second arg can be a list, rather than an `Alternatives` construct. The author no longer recalls the reason for this difference. Possibly indifference, at the time. Or maybe just that `DependsOnQ` is not pattern-based.

Answer (score 2):

Probably (ok, most likely) not the most elegant way. But here we go: May be you can let $x=f_x$ and $y=f_y$ and use `CoefficientList` to help.

```
ClearAll[x, y, a, b, c, h, r, lhs, rhs]
fx = D[f[x, y], x];
fy = D[f[x, y], y];
expr = a fx + b/2 fx fy + c h fx == fx + Exp[a] fx + 3 fx fy + 2 b h fx
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
expr = expr /. {fx -> x, fy -> y}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
lhs = Last@CoefficientList[expr /. (lhs_ == rhs_) :> lhs, {x, y}];
rhs = Last@CoefficientList[expr /. (lhs_ == rhs_) :> rhs, {x, y}];
(r = MapThread[Equal, {lhs, rhs}]) // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One small part left

```
r2 = r[[1]] /. (h any_ + __) :> h any;
r2 /. (any1_ h == any2_ h) :> any1 == any2
Inner[Subtract, r[[1]], r2, Equal]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. This does work, but it seems this requires quite a bit of inspection. For what I'm working on, I will need to deal with many partial derivative terms (perhaps hundreds) and picking them out by hand this way would be unfeasible. Is there any more automated solution?

Comment: @DavidZhang as I said, it is not the most automated method, but unless some Mathematica parsing expert steps in and can see a more direct way, I thought this might be a start. The transformation you are asking for is not a common one, and I could not think of a more direct way myself.....